# Where to set link to go when manipulating DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I manipulate the DOM, like adding or removing a div when a user clicks a link, I have the link that initiates the DOM manipulation going to "#". Where should the href parameter point to if I want to page to stay at the page position it is currently at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: ah was trying to remember this :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your click handler return false; this will prevent the browser from following the link.

Answer (score 0):

put in your link

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">My Link</a>
```

If you want to do a javascript call, you can put in any js before the return false

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">Not really a link!</a>
```

*fixed*

Comment: Note, that without a value in HREF, IE will not recognize it as a link, and in IE 7 and IE 6 the :hover property won't work.  You are best to put in the href="#"

Comment: fair enough, but who supports IE anyway ;) joke. If only that was true :(

Answer (score 0):

The function that gets called on click should return FALSE to stop the anchor from following through.

```
<script>
    function onClick() {
        // do click work
        return false;
    }
</script>

<a href='#' onclick='javascript:onClick'>Click Me</a>
```